# Watin 2 and IE 9 Download Manager

Tags: internet-explorer-9, watin, download-manager

Has anybody got their Automation using Watin 2 (latest release) work with IE 9 Download Manager?

Some of the issues I am facing are:
1. Cannot grab the control ids of the button on the Download Manager (Save, Save As...) using Dev Toolbar which makes it difficult to click a button using watin
2. The only workaround I have found is to use SendKeys. Like Alt + S (and others) to save a file. However, I cannot send keys to use Save As and other options in the ancillary menu.
I would like to interact with the Download Manager which may allow me to use Save As.

Comment: I also had some problem downloading files using Watin 2.1 and IE9, so I reverted to IE8 where it works.

Comment: I still waiting for someone to throw some light on this. Does this mean that we cannot handle IE 9 Download Manager? Really?

Comment: The main problem is that the document manager window is actually a child window of IE and not a web page itself.  This is why you can't find it using the Dev Toolbar.

Comment: Ah, thank you. But is there a way to automate / handle this download manager at all? I can't seem to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Watin can't find download dialog and dialog buttons. It can resolve with this.

[How to test file download with Watin / IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500339/how-to-test-file-download-with-watin-ie9/8532222#8532222)

See comments

Comment: You might at least want to add the gist of the answer/cause of the problem to your answer instead of just adding a link. [This thread on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) goes into that issue.