# None of the buttons(Save, Open, Cancel) attributes in IE developer tool not show up

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Requirement is to download the Excel file from IE9 browser. I could able to click the Download button using Web driver in Java by which new window is displayed as shown below:

[image]
When I am trying to view the attributes of save button in IE developer tool, tool could not recognize them. Please help where is the problem with this window or how to resolve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Those buttons are not part of the web page, they are created by IE internally, so you can't look at them in dev tools

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752283/webdriver-ie9-setup-auto-download-files