# With C# 4.0, the System.Windows.Window constructor doesn't support any arguments

Tags: c#, .net, watin, filedialog

I would like to implement this suggestion: [How to test file download with Watin / IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500339/how-to-test-file-download-with-watin-ie9/8532222#8532222)

In the project, I added the references that poster referred to:

- UIAutomationClient
- UIAutomationTypes

However, Window wasn't resolved.  So I added the following two references which resolved Window:

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework

However, the System.Windows.Window constructor doesn't support any arguments, yet the poster has an argument:

```
Window windowMain = new Window(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.GetWindow(browser.hWnd, 5));
```

The poster states that their solution works with .net 4 which is what my project is using, and it's full framework, not the client profile.  Is the use of PresentationCore/Framework incorrect?  I did try a reference to System.Windows.Forms, but Window isn't a class of it.

Let me be exceptionally clear as to what I'm trying achieve as I guess it wasn't obvious enough.  I would like to implement the poster's solution as noted in the link in the first sentence of my question.  Adding the references to UIAutomationClient/Types didn't resolve the Window object.  So, I went looking for Window in the framework and found it in PresentationCore/Framework.  By the response I got, I obviously shouldn't be using PresentationCore/Framework.  So that's why I asked the question.

Comment: what??? PresentationCore.dll and PresentationFramework.dll are part of WPF. I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but NO the `Window` class in WPF does not have any parameterized constructors.

Comment: Although the type of windowMain is declared to be System.Window.Window, I believe it is actually an instance of a derived object. Note that the full name is given for the declarator, but not for the instantiator.

Comment: Makes sense.  At first I thought Window was part of the IE object that Watin provides but I couldn't find it.  Pieter Geerkens was correct.  It's found in WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Pieter Geerkens answered the question.  Window is found in WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.