# Curl Loader vs SSIS

Tags: curl, ssis

I want to know whether ssis of Microsoft can be used for simulating the user activity in a web page (log in, go to tab1 and so on) to download a file and if it is posible how can I achieve this...???

I also want to know whether there's any posibility to integrate curl loader whithin ssis so that I can achieve the objective I mentioned above.

Thanks in advice guys.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is a .NET based ETL engine. Because of the .NET aspect, you could use an SSIS Script Task to write C#/VB.NET code to simulate user activity.

You won't though as it'd be the equivalent of buying an F1 race car and go off-roading with it. It has wheels and it'll probably work but it won't be an enjoyable or inexpensive endeavor.

Writing the .NET is probably going to entail the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class unless you want to get into the specific request and response objects. You will probably be better served creating a dedicated .NET application versus creating an SSIS package with a single Script Task as it'd be the right tool for the job.

As to whether you can integrate Curl Loader, maybe? If it's a non-graphical tool you can use command line parameters to have it crawl a site, then yes. An Execute Process Task can fire it off and all is good. If it requires user input, then Execute Process Task still works but you have the wrong tool. SSIS is designed to not have user interactivity. It's a high horsepower tool for moving data about.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't using curl but alternatively you could create a C# console application using [Watin](http://watin.org/) to launch a copy of Internet Explorer, find the username and password box, fill in the credentials, submit the details and then download the required file.

The answer below should help you navigate the download dialogs.

[How to test file download with Watin / IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500339/how-to-test-file-download-with-watin-ie9/8532222#8532222)

After you have your application just launch it using an "Execute Process Task".
Once your file is downloaded you can complete the rest of your ETL process.