# UIAutomation: InvokePattern throws "hotkey already registered" exception

Tags: c#, watin, microsoft-ui-automation

I followed a tip in this stackoverflow thread ([IE9 File Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500339/how-to-test-file-download-with-watin-ie9/8532222#8532222)) which includes UIAutomation and it almost always works.

But sometimes the Invoke method throws an exception which says "Hotkey already registered" (or in (original) German: "Diese Abkürzungstaste ist bereits registriert").

Here's the critical code section (somewhat modified compared to the code in thread mentioned above):

```
bool bInvoke = (bool)element.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.IsInvokePatternAvailableProperty);
if (bInvoke)
{
    InvokePattern click = element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
    try
    {
        click.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invoke error! "+e.Message);
    }
}
```

Q: What does the exception message mean, and how to avoid it?

Comment: You must include the stack trace of the exception to get help with this.  Pretty unlikely that UIAutomation is using RegisterHotKey(), be sure to distinguish exceptions in your own code from exceptions that are triggered in the app that you are automating.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; unfortunately the error occurs not 'reliably' and on production machine - but sure, the stack trace ... should have thought about that.

Comment: You're not doing something that results in a nested dialog, are you?  That *could* result in any hotkeys being registered twice.

Comment: At least I am not aware of a nested dialog. Before I posted the question I investigated the window-hierarchy and it looked pretty straight forward.

Comment: btw: I found that my dev/ test machine is running on IE10, my production machine on IE9. So in my desperation I upgraded to IE10. From initial tests this seems to help.