# How to find browser download folder path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using WatIn making login to webSite and downloading file.I dont have to much power on download dialog sow when i see download dialog i just press save button and file downloading to defaul folder of broser,AND this is exactly what i need the path to this folder.I know that basicly it `C:\Users\UserNAme\Favorites\Downloads` but i need to bee 100% sure because user can change this path.

How to find last downloaded file path or the default download folder of broser.

here my code  for download if any one need

```
Thread.Sleep(10000);
IntPtr prevChild = FindWindow("IEFrame", "Reports | ACCESS - Internet Explorer");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
IntPtr currChild = FindWindowEx(prevChild, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", "");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
IntPtr currChild2 = FindWindowEx(currChild, 0, "DirectUIHWND", "");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
PostMessage(currChild2, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F6, 2);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
PostMessage(currChild2, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 2);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
PostMessage(currChild2, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ENTER, 2);
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500339/how-to-test-file-download-with-watin-ie9

Comment: I am familiar with this post.I used this method many time,but i didn't see there any thin that can show me the path to defaul folder,but thanx any way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE 11: default it will go to %homedrive%%homepath%\downloads or %userprofile%\downloads - result is the same. If its not default there will be a REG_SZ value with name 'Default Download Directory' in key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main'

EDIT:

```
String path = String.Empty;
RegistryKey rKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main");
   if (rKey != null)
       path = (String)rKey.GetValue("Default Download Directory");
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
       path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\downloads";
```