# how to current get download path from browser settings

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to get the current download path from browser settings (chrome,firefox,IE) in C#.
I am working with selenium and having some tests which contains file download option. I am able to download the file successfully via my test but having issue with the verification with file download. I have no way to verify whether the download was successful or not. So I am thinking to get the current download location of the browser which most of the time will be "\\downloads" and to check for the file exists at the location first.

I will be executing my tests on different servers and browsers so I cant relay on the static "\\downloads" location need to get the current download path from the browser.
is there any way I can get this download path in C# with the selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to get the Downloads path,

```
string user = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string download = Path.Combine(user, "Downloads");
```

EDIT: This could be useful to you. [How to find browser download folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671848/how-to-find-browser-download-folder-path)